# How setup a leaflet map to show a WMS layer in ESRI:102012 projection?

Tags: projection, leaflet, wms, srs, proj

I have some layers on a wms server that are in ESRI:102012 srs. http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102012/

The server accepts getmap requests with EPSG:102012 srs.

I'm using a proj4leaflet plugin to set the appropriate projection.
But I'm stuck with defining L.Transformation, resolutions and scales. Can anybody tell me what the parameters should be or provide the example?

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's an example of how you can set up these parameters for the ESRI:102012 projection in Leaflet using the proj4leaflet plugin

```js
// Define the ESRI:102012 projection
proj4.defs("ESRI:102012", "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs");

// Create a CRS object for the ESRI:102012 projection
var crs = new L.Proj.CRS("ESRI:102012",
    "+proj=laea +lat_0=45 +lon_0=-100 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6370997 +b=6370997 +units=m +no_defs", {
        resolutions: [8192, 4096, 2048, 1024, 512], // Define the resolutions for different zoom levels
        origin: [0, 0], // Define the origin in projected coordinates
        bounds: L.bounds([Number.MIN_VALUE, Number.MIN_VALUE], [Number.MAX_VALUE, Number.MAX_VALUE]) // Set the bounds
});

// Create the map with the ESRI:102012 projection
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: crs
});

// Set the initial view and center of the map
map.setView([0, 0], 4);

// Add a WMS layer with the ESRI:102012 projection
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://your-wms-server-url', {
    layers: 'your-wms-layer-name',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true
}).addTo(map);
```